# New API keys generated for v7 do not work with v5

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have an application making use of the py-ms-cognitive wrapper (https://github.com/tristantao/py-ms-cognitive) for Cognitive Services.

As far as I can see in the code, it uses `v5.0` of the `Cognitive Services API`, and the API keys that I have now are for `v7.0`.

This is the error message I receive when using a valid subscription key for `v7.0` of the API:

```
{ 
  "statusCode": 401, 
  "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." 
}
```

I'd like to know how to navigate this issue - surely this breaks all existing production keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v7 API keys are meant for v7 endpoints. They won't work with v5 APIs. If you have v7 keys, just make calls to v7 APIs. Mostly, it requires changing **v5** to **v7** in your API calls.

Alternately, you can use py samples from cognitive services documentation. For websearch API for example, you can take py sample from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/python. Similarly, all APIs (e.g. news, image, video, custom, etc.) have py samples. The samples you are using are for v5 and hence they are not working with v7 APIs.

Comment: Appreciate it! I handled it that way, and it all works.